# Insert one value of an array into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I currently have a script that outputs an array. The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [pattern] => 12369
)
```

I only want to insert 12369 into my database.table in column 'pattern'. How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know what your keys and values will be and have control over them, this is a generic solution.

```
$keys = implode(' ,', array_keys($array));
$values = implode(' ,', $array);

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO database.table ($keys) VALUES ($values)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Insert into mytable (pattern) values($arr['pattern');
```

Comment: I'd prefer using prepared statements for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,this is a very simple program to insert any data in your database....

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","DBName");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO TableName(pattern)
    VALUES ('12369')");

     mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: Yeah, this is just an allround script for inserting values. This doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: You can use implode function either...

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");
/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}


$query="INSERT INTO table ('pattern') VALUES ('".$array['pattern']."')";
if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
    printf("value successfully inserted .\n");
}
```